# Is there a manual for the neuralnetwork package? If so, where can I find it?

Tags: diagrams

The neuralnetwork package looks very handy and I would like to use it. I want to find a manual for it before I do, however The README file explains a few things but I hope there is more than that.

Comment: I wrote before that it is an example and probably not a real package because the command `texdoc neutralnetwork` gave me just an image. But I found out that the info you need is in its readme file: https://github.com/battlesnake/neural/blob/master/README

Comment: Assuming that the GitHub repo contains everything, there is the README and the examples (and the code of the package itself, of course), nothing more.

Comment: Thanks. By using the README file and the examples, I was able to do what I wanted for now. It remains to be seen whether or not it will be that easy with other things I may wish to do in the future.

Answer (score 3):

To summarize the comments:

Assuming that the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/battlesnake/neural/) contains everything, there is no manual, but three other places to find information:

- The [README](https://github.com/battlesnake/neural/blob/master/README)
- The [examples](https://github.com/battlesnake/neural/tree/master/examples)
- The [package code itself](https://github.com/battlesnake/neural/blob/master/neuralnetwork.sty)

In addition, if there are specific things you don't quite understand, you can always ask a question for example here on TeX.SX.